# NativeScript not working below android 4.4

Tags: nativescript

[image]

Tried on emulate and run on physical device below android 4.4. It just not work and come out with this error.

Comment: It should be supported... Are you sure your problem doesn't come from the emulator? It seems that you have not allocated enough memory for the virtual device.

Comment: Already set to 1024 RAM and still getting the same error. Testing on physical android 4.0. Not able to install as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't test app on physical android 4.0. NativeScript supports only devices with Android 4.2 (API level 17) or newer.

Comment: But it don't even works on --avd --geny  android 2.3

Comment: vzhen - it won't work on anything that is below android version 4.2 -- Real or Emulated.  It must be on a 4.2 or higher device.